# How to pull element from array MongoDB php?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
"parameters" : [
    {
        "592193d6470e6cf80d3c9874" : {
            "Speed" : "1",
            "Acceleration" : "2"
        }
    }]
```

I need to pull element by key `592193d6470e6cf80d3c9874`.

I tried:

```
 $this->collection->update(
            [],
            ['$unset' => ['parameters' => $id]], ['multiple' => true]);
```

Where `$id` id `592193d6470e6cf80d3c9874`.

Comment: $this->collection->update([],['$unset' => ['parameters' => null]], ['multiple' => true]);

Comment: $this->collection->update([],['$unset' => ['parameters.'.$parameterId => null]], ['multiple' => true]);   .... try

Comment: what do you mean by pull ? you want to delete that document ?

Comment: It does not work: `$this->collection->update([],['$unset' => ['parameters.'.$id => null]], ['multiple' => true]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->collection->update(['$unset' => ['parameters'=> ['_id'] => $id], ['multiple' => true]);
```

or

```
$this->collection->update(['$unset' => ['parameters.'.$parameterId => null]], ['multiple' => true]);
```

Comment: Okay man, thank you, can I ask you, how to add in parameters? I tried: `$this->collection->update(
                    ["prototype_id" => $id],
                    ['$set' => ["parameters" => array(array($key => $data))]],
                    ["multiple" => true]);
` It overwrites all parameters

Comment: And does not work you sample, cause parameters is array

Comment: $this->collection->update(['$unset' => ['parameters'=> ['_id'] => $id], ['multiple' => true]);

Comment: Can you give me your private contact?

Comment: kumarrishikesh12@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent email :)